# Connect Netsuite restlet with OAuth

Tags: netsuite

I Try to connect my restlet with OAuth in netsuite But unanble to connect it. Checking with restlet console it saying

> "SESSION_TIMED_OUT". 
>   Content-Type: application/json
>   OAuth oauth_consumer_key="e7683b63_like_key_31772de0e297",oauth_token="00076e_token_34c87d6367ab456fd2".

can anybody help , what am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

I would think that if you're getting a Session Timeout, that either the RESTLet  operation is exceeding the time allotment, OR you are making concurrent RESTLet calls which haven't completed.

Here's a list of RESTLet status codes:
https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/19202